# MySQL DATETIME to DATE query JPQL

Tags: java, mysql, date, datetime, jpa

```
query = em.createQuery("SELECT COUNT(a) FROM Appointment a WHERE a.datetime >= ?1 and a.datetime < ?2");
query.setParameter(1, date1, TemporalType.DATE);
query.setParameter(1, date2, TemporalType.DATE);
```

So JPQL does not have a DATE() function.
    I've tried a.startDate >= day1 AND a.startDate < nextday
but it is returning the count of every single appointment

Comment: Yes. The ?1 is for the parameter value. 
The error is marking the first parenthesis in DATE(a.startDate)

Comment: startDate is DATETIME

Comment: what is count(a) ? shouldn't be count(a.*) ?

Comment: Because DATE is not a valid JPQL function. Read the JPA spec and any decent JPQL docs

Comment: what is the SQL generated?

Answer (score 1):

This query:

```
SELECT COUNT(a)
FROM Appointment a
WHERE DATE(a.startDate) = ?1
```

only makes sense of there is a column called `a` in `Appointment`.  That is unlikely.  You probably intend:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Appointment a
WHERE DATE(a.startDate) = ?1
```

Comment: @Entity . . . Your question has the "mysql" tag.  And, that syntax doesn't really make sense in MySQL.